# PHP Require not showing up

Tags: php, html, require

i've got a weird problem here. I'm trying to include a footer for my website via the php require() function, but it doesnt show up, in stead it shows a link redirecting me to http://cjtekkit.net/function.require

Check out the problem yourself at http://cjtekkit.net/

The weird thing, i did the same exact thing for the header and buttons at the top of the site, but the bottom part won't cooperate.

Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: can you show the code that you have placed in the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

`http://cjtekkit.net/main_look_bottom.html` - Not Found

The file `main_look_bottom.html` is missing, `main_look_top.html` exists - that's you are able to set the header.

Comment: Oh god, DERP! uploaded it to the wrong site. God.. how can i be so stupid xD

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the error message that PHP is giving you, but is not visible because of the styles of your page. If you view the source in your browser you will see it:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  require(/home/woutegx92/domains/cjtekkit.net/public_html/main_look_bottom.html) [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>/home/woutegx92/domains/cjtekkit.net/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/woutegx92/domains/cjtekkit.net/public_html/main_look_bottom.html' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/woutegx92/domains/cjtekkit.net/public_html/index.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
```

And it means that the file you are trying to include does not exist.